# Create table with field type text creating as memo

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

the following

```
            "CREATE table " & acObj.pullTBLNAME & " ( DATES number,A Text, B Text, C Text, D Text, E Text, F number, G number,H number)"
```

is creating a table with data types of number and data types of MEMO not the desired type of TEXT.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: use Char(50) instead of Text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a field size:

```
"CREATE table " & acObj.pullTBLNAME & _
" ( DATES number,A Text(20), B Text(255), C Text, " & _
"D Text, E Text, F number, G number,H number)"
```

Comment: Would this syntax work with Sql Server?  I'm getting an error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @zooropa This is MS Access (Jet/ACE) SQL. You need t-sql, which you will find in tags, or sql-server, ditto. Search example http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bt-sql%5D+create+table

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
  (DATES number, A CHAR,...)
```

works as well.

Comment: Does it work in Jet/ACE? I don't know myself, as I almost never use DDL with Jet/ACE, but since you're suggesting it, you surely tested in in Access/Jet/ACE, right?